# Using class/struct not defined in .lib

Tags: c++, directx-11

I'm currently writing a bunch of functions and classes for rendering and organizing `vertex` data. I also want to provide these functions and classes as a `.lib`.
The problem is that these functions and classes need to know how the `struct vertex` looks like (i.e. the definition of it) at creation time of the `.lib` (because they make use of `std::vector<Vertex>`).
However I would like to use the library functions and classes for different `vertex` definitions since the properties of the `vertex` might change depending on which model to draw.

**Is there any way to build the `.lib` without determining the `vertex` structure?**

Comment: Unless you make ``Vertex`` the union of all possible data, then you'll need distinct structs for each vertex organization and therefore need unique instances of ``std::vector<>``. You could just use 'generic binary blobs' with flexible layouts (i.e. Vertex Buffers) and pass them around as ``std::vector<uint8_t>`` along with an input layout description. See [DirectXMesh](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh) and [DirectXTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

My original answer was assuming templates, which you say you're not using. Side note: using a template for your type `Vertex` would work, but the library would have to become a header-only library. You should seriously consider this option.

If you don't want this, then perhaps an interface approach would work (provided you're happy with the performance penalty). For example, for `Vertex`:

```
class Vertex
{
public:
    virtual double getX() = 0;
    virtual double getY() = 0;
    ...
};
```

Then perhaps a factory for creating them:

```
class VertexFactory
{
public:
    virtual Vertex* createVertex(double x, double y) = 0;
};
```

The your library could have some code like this:

```
void doStuff(VertexFactory* fac)
{
    std::vector<Vertex*> vertices;

    for(int i = 0, i < 100; ++i)
        vertices.push_back(fac->createVertex(i, i));

    //then do some other stuff
}
```

And your client code could use it like this:

```
class MyVertex : public Vertex
{
public:
    double getX() override { return 1.0; }
    double getY() override { return 2.0; }
};

class MyVertexFactory : public VertexFectory
{
public:
    MyVertex* createVertex(double x, double y) override
    {
         return new MyVertex;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    MyVertexFactory fac;
    doStuff(&fac);
}
```

Comment: My vertex is just a ordinary struct. No template is used right now

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a vector of pointers, (or smart pointers, but then you need to publish some interface).
Another option is that the objects you get back from the library are stubs to the actual objects. Alternate libraries would need to work within your "pimpl".
A bunch of functions isn't very object-oriented, though. You might consider publishing an interface class so you can have a vector of smart pointers to the interface.

Comment: So I should use only std::vector<Vertex*> everywhere, so that I can forward declare the vertex and thus the classes don't need to know the vertex definition when creating the .lib?

Comment: Yes. That will work. You will have to provide your own new and destroy methods as well. This is the old-skool C library.